# Plot time series of different years together

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I am trying to compare different years' variables but I am having trouble plotting them together.
The time series is a temperature series which can be found in https://github.com/gonzalodqa/timeseries as temp.csv
I would like to plot something like the image but I find it difficult to subset the months between the years and then combine the lines in the same plot under the same months
[image]

If someone can give some advice or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Given that your data is very clean, all you need is to learn the right ggplot lingo to solve this. You can refer to https://rpubs.com/Mentors_Ubiqum/ggplot_geom_line_1 for example. If you still have doubts, edit the question

Comment: I tried to plot 
```` ggplot(temp,aes(date,t42,color=year)+geom_line````
thinking it might plot each year individually but it did not. I think I will check the link. I am very new with time series

Comment: The problem is that you don't want `date` on the x-axis, as it will want to plot 1-2020 on a different point than 1-2021. If you refer to the picture you posted in your question you can figure out which column needs to be on the x-axis instead

Comment: so you want your chart to start from Jul?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way.

The first chart shows all the available temperatures, the second chart is aggregated by month.

In the first chart, we force the same year so that `ggplot` will plot them aligned, but we separate the lines by colour.

For the second one, we just use `month` as `x` variable and `year` as `colour` variable.

Note that:

- with `scale_x_datetime` we can hide the year so that no one can see that we forced the year 2020 to every observation
- with `scale_x_continous` we can show the name of the months instead of the numbers

[just try to run the charts with and without `scale_x_...` to understand what I'm talking about]

`month.abb` is a useful default variable for months names.

```r
# read data
df <- readr::read_csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gonzalodqa/timeseries/main/temp.csv")


# libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


# line chart by datetime
df %>% 
  # make datetime: force unique year
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::make_datetime(2020, month, day, hour, minute, second)) %>% 
  
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = datetime, y = T42, colour = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = lubridate::make_datetime(2020,1:12), labels = month.abb) +
  labs(title = "Temperature by Datetime", colour = "Year")
```

[image]

```r
# line chart by month
df %>% 
  
  # average by year-month
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise(T42 = mean(T42, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = T42, colour = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = month.abb, minor_breaks = NULL) +
  labs(title = "Average Temperature by Month", colour = "Year")
```

[image]

---

In case you want your chart to start from July, you can use this code instead:

```r
months_order <- c(7:12,1:6)

# line chart by month
df %>% 
  
  # average by year-month
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise(T42 = mean(T42, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% 
    
  # create new groups starting from each July
  group_by(neworder = cumsum(month == 7)) %>% 
    
  # keep only complete years
  filter(n() == 12) %>% 
    
  # give new names to groups
  mutate(years = paste(unique(year), collapse = " / ")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  
  # reorder months
  mutate(month = factor(month, levels = months_order, labels = month.abb[months_order], ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
      
  # plot
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = T42, colour = years, group = years)) +
  labs(title = "Average Temperature by Month", colour = "Year")
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To have something similar to the first plot but starting from July, you could use the following code:

```r
# libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


# custom months order
months_order <- c(7:12,1:6)

# fake dates for plot
# note: choose 4 to include 29 Feb which exist only in leap years
dates <- make_datetime(c(rep(3,6), rep(4,6)), months_order)

# line chart by datetime
df %>%
  
  # create date time
  mutate(datetime = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)) %>%
  
  # filter years of interest
  filter(datetime >= make_datetime(2018,7), datetime < make_datetime(2020,7)) %>%
  
  # create increasing group after each july
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  mutate(dummy = month(datetime) == 7 & datetime == min(datetime)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(dummy = cumsum(dummy)) %>%
  
  # force unique years and create custom name
  group_by(dummy) %>%
  mutate(datetime = datetime - years(year - 4) - years(month>=7),
         years = paste(unique(year), collapse = " / ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  # plot
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = datetime, y = T42, colour = years)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = dates, labels = month.abb[months_order]) +
  labs(title = "Temperature by Datetime", colour = "Year")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed. I was looking at the link provided but it averages the data and the first figure you provided shows what I am looking for

Comment: I tried to plot the first time of time series in the Jul-Jun format but I get really strange-looking figures. Is there an additional mutate that I should use?

Comment: well, yeah.. wait a sec

Comment: Okay, I made a new edit to my answer

Comment: That is amazong! thank you very much this will really help me a lot processing my other datasets

Answer (score 1):

To order month differently and sum up the values in couples of years, you've to work a bit with your data before plotting them:

```
library(dplyr)     # work data
library(ggplot2)   # plots
library(lubridate) # date
library(readr)     # fetch data

# your data
df <- read_csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gonzalodqa/timeseries/main/temp.csv")


  df %>%
  mutate(date = make_date(year, month,day)) %>%
  # reorder month
  group_by(month_2 = factor(as.character(month(date, label = T, locale = Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English"))),
                            levels = c('Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun')),
           # group years as you like
           year_2   = ifelse( year(date) %in% (2018:2019), '2018/2019', '2020/2021')) %>%
  # you can put whatever aggregation function you need
  summarise(val = mean(T42, na.rm = T)) %>%
  # plot it!
  ggplot(aes(x = month_2, y = val, color = year_2, group = year_2)) + 
  geom_line()   + 
  ylab('T42')   +
  xlab('month') + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution without the all dates to 2020 trick.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <- read_csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gonzalodqa/timeseries/main/temp.csv")
df <- df |>
  filter(year %in% c(2018, 2019, 2020)) %>%
  mutate(year = factor(year),
         month = ifelse(month<10, paste0(0,month), month),
         day = paste0(0, day),
         month_day = paste0(month, "-", day))
df |> ggplot(aes(x=month_day, y=T42, group=year, col=year)) +
        geom_line() +
        scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("01-01", "02-01", "03-01", "04-01", "05-01", "06-01", "07-01", "08-01", "09-01", "10-01", "11-01", "12-01"))
```